# In a weighted undirected graph of n nodes, what is the minimum cost of visiting any distinct k nodes?

Tags: graph-algorithm

Here the different k nodes are visitees, they are visited by visitors. The challenge is that, the number of visitors, who are visitors, who are the k distinct visitees, and the visiting path (from visitor to visitees) all need to be decided. The rule is that a visitee can not be a vistor. Here are several examples:

If k=1, we just find the edge with minimum weight in the graph, say (u,v), then either u is the visitor (then v is visitee) or v is the visitor (then u is the visitee). The minimum cost is this minimum weight.

if k=2, we just find the two edges with minimum weights in the graph, say (u,v) and (u',v'). If u,v, u',v' are four different nodes, then any node in one of the two edges can be visitor and the other node is visitee. If one node from both edges is the same, say v=u', then we can say u is the visitor and v, v' are the visitees, or v' is the visitor and v, u are visitees, which are both optimal solution.

if k=3, however, finding the three minimum weighted edges does not necessarily give optimal solution. Here is an example. Say, edges (u,v), (v,u'), and (v,v') are those three edges. We can say that u visits both v and u'. However, since v is being visited, it can not be the visitor to visit v'. But v' can not be the visitor that visits v either, since v can only be visited once. In this case, we have to find the fourth-minimum edge.

The maximum value of k could be n-1, in which case, we should find one visitor to visit all other n-1 visitees using the least cost. Here unlike TSP, it is possible a node is visited multiple times, since our graph is not a complete graph. To map this problem to TSP: we want to visit any k cities (the visitees) out of n cities using least cost - to achieve that, we don't mind to have as many as possible salesmen (the visitors), and we don't mind which city they start at, we care about k cities are being visited, and it is possible a city is visited multiple times; besides, the n cities do not form complete graph.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. What have you tried?

Comment: There is optimal solution in linear topology (the k least-weight edges are the optimal solution). My current solution for general topology is: find the k least-weight edges, then try to fix the case of (u,v), (v,u'), and (v,v') mentioned above, by finding the next cheapest edge so on and so forth, so that rule 1: a visitee can not be a vistor and rule 2: a visitee can only be visited once are both be satisfied. Not sure if this is optimal though, because what if for k=3, there is another edge (v, v''), and v' vising v'' by way of v is part of the optimal solution?

Comment: Sorry the rule 2 above is not correct: there must be k distinct visitees, but each visitee can be visited more than once, if that reduces visiting cost. Thanks